# How to pass a Object^ to a native function in C++ CLI

Tags: c++-cli, clr

I'm new to C++ CLI and I still don't get the new pointers and handles.

I have a native function which opens a window. It requires a handle to a parent window:

```
void open(void* parentHwnd);
```

How am I supposed to pass a parent window from managed code to this function? I was trying to do something like this:

```
void managedOpen(Object^ parent)
{
   interior_ptr<void> ptr = &*parent);
   open(ptr);
}
```

but the & operator "cannot be used to take the address of an object with a ref class type".

Also should I use `pin_ptr` instead of `interior_ptr`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Picking proper types in an interop scenario is 99% of the battle.  You didn't get any help from the existing code, `void*` is not an appropriate type to use for a window handle.  It should be `HWND`.  That ship probably sailed a long time ago.

But on top of the list of types *never* to use is System::Object.  That only ever interops correctly by sheer accident, unless you interop with COM code that uses variants.  The appropriate type to store an operating system handle in managed code is `IntPtr` or `SafeHandle`.  Heavily biased to IntPtr for window handles since there isn't anything safe about them, they'll die beyond your control when the user closes a window.

So this needs to look like this:

```
void managedOpen(IntPtr parent)
{
   open(parent.ToPointer());
}
```

With the burden on the client code to produce a valid IntPtr.  Could be Control.Handle in Winforms or WindowInteropHelper.Handle in WPF, etcetera.

Answer (score 0):

Stuff like System::Object is only passed from managed to unmanaged with intention of passing it back to managed code, such as a managed function calling `EnumWindows`. But in this case:

- In C++/CLI, you can simply pass a pointer to an unmanaged object containing a `gcroot<>` to the managed object you want to access.
- In C#, you use the `GCHandle` class to obtain an `IntPtr` and back.